# FLEX/YACC End of the first line in multiline input

Tags: yacc, eof, lex

Once again I go here for advice, thanks in advance.
I have simple parser to parse the chars and summ the numbers together.
When I have just one line, it is ok but it should read from file, where multiple lines are.
It goues to the end of derivation and when it should take STMTS + '\n' it says 'invalid character'. It does not see the \n.

```
        //lex
%{
#include "kfloat.tab.h"
%}

%option nounput
%option noinput

%%
[ \t]   ;

[0-9]+  { yylval.d=atof(yytext); return NUMBER; }
"sqrt"  {return iSQRT; }
"log"   {return iLOG; }
"+"     { return OPLUS; } 
"-"     { return OMINUS; }
"*"     { return OMULT; } 
"/"     { return ODIV; } 
"("     { return LPAR; }
")"     { return RPAR; }
"\n"    { yylineno++; return yytext[0]; }
";"     { return EOL;}
.   return yytext[0];
%%

//yacc

%{
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define YYDEBUG 1
void yyerror(char *);
int yylex(void);
extern int yylineno;

%}
%union { double d;}
%token <d> NUMBER
%token EOL
%type <d> EXP STMT 
%left OPLUS OMINUS
%left OMULT ODIV
%left iLOG iSQRT 
%left LPAR RPAR


%%
STMTS : STMTS STMT EOL {printf("END of deriv :2 and MORE statements- now EOF and next line\n");} //edit
      | STMT EOL {printf("END of deriv :ONE statement - now EOF and next line\n");} //edit
      | STMTS '\n'  //edit
     ;
STMT : EXP
     |   
     ;
EXP  : EXP OPLUS EXP   {$$=$1+$3; printf("ENDdddd1111:  %f\n",$1);}
     | EXP OMINUS EXP  {$$=$1-$3;}
     | EXP OMULT EXP   {$$=$1*$3;}
     | EXP ODIV EXP    {if ($3==0) {yyerror("Zatim nelze delit nulou"); exit(0);} else {$$=$1/$3;}}
     | LPAR EXP RPAR   { ;}
     | iSQRT EXP       {$$=sqrt($2);}
     | iLOG EXP        {$$=log10($2);}
     | OPLUS EXP       {$$= $2;}
     | OMINUS EXP      {$$= -$2;}
     | NUMBER          {$$= $1;}
     ;

%%

/* lineno do erroru printf*/

int main(void)
{
#if YYDEBUG
  yydebug = 1;
#endif
  if(!yyparse ())
    printf("OK\n");
  return 0;
}
  
void yyerror (char *s)
{
   printf("Syntakticka chyba: %s na radku: %i\n",s,yylineno);
}
```

And when executed, in the end everything looks fine, except it wont combine STMTS with '\n'.
What am I doing wrong in this case please?

- EOL is ';' - it should be the end of "equation"
- Line example: (+5+-5)*8--10;

```
Stack now 0 8 17
Reducing stack by rule 2 (line 28):
   $1 = nterm STMT ()
   $2 = token EOL ()
**-> $$ = nterm STMTS ()
Entering state 7
Stack now 0 7
Reading a token
Next token is token "invalid token" ()**
Error: popping nterm STMTS ()
Stack now 0
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token "invalid token" ()
Stack now 0
ENDdddd1111:  5.000000
ENDddd333:  10.000000
Syntakticka chyba: syntax error na radku: 1
```

EDIT: OK, I am a bit further:
Added '\n' as endline into a parser.y. Lex is the same. Now it works for manually inserted strings in bash - first string - the action in second STMTS is called, second string - first STMTS is called.... seems good. But when I try to parse input from file, I get invalid charcter again when it should be EOF:

```
//from file 
END of deriv :ONE statement - now EOF and next line
-> $$ = nterm STMTS ()
Entering state 7
Stack now 0 7
Reading a token
Next token is token "invalid token" ()   //should be '\n'
Syntaktick▒ chyba
Error: popping nterm STMTS ()
Stack now 0
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token "invalid token" ()
Stack now 0

// manual insert - same string
END of deriv :ONE statement - now EOF and next line
-> $$ = nterm STMTS ()
Entering state 7
Stack now 0 7
Reading a token
Next token is token '\n' ()
Shifting token '\n' ()
Entering state 16
Stack now 0 7 16
Reducing stack by rule 3 (line 26):
   $1 = nterm STMTS ()
   $2 = token '\n' ()
-> $$ = nterm STMTS ()
Entering state 7
Stack now 0 7
Reading a token


// Content of input file:
(+12-9);
sqrt(16);
```

If I try to input those manually, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lexer returns the token `'\n'` for newline, but the parser is not expecting it.  If you want to have a newline end a STMT, you need a rule that expects that -- something like `STMTS : STMT '\n'`.

Alternately, change your lexer to ignore newlines.  You probably want to ignore other whitespace as well, so something like

```
[ \t\r\n]         ;
```

in the lex code

Comment: I've added the '\n' EOF into the STMTS and it works. But just for input, not input from file. There, the EOF is invalid token again. See EDIT changes in .Y file.

Comment: Problem was really in the \r. There was CR on the end of line in file. Lots of work...but "If you do not burn, you do not know the fire"
Thanks again Mister Dodd.